# тег label по центру по вертикали относительно чебокса?

Tags: html, css3

```css
.search_on {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.search_on .select_item {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.search_on .select_item .checkbox {
    display: none;
}

input {
    border: none;
}
.search_on .select_item .label_checkbox {
    height: 20px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.filter .options label {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.filter .options .search_on .select_item .label_checkbox span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: museo_sans_cyrl300;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.search_on .select_item .checkbox+label>.checkbox_square {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #aa2b2b;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
.animate_background, .search_on .select_item .checkbox+label>.checkbox_square {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
.search_on .select_item .label_checkbox span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: museo_sans_cyrl700;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.filter .options .search_on .select_item .label_checkbox span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: museo_sans_cyrl300;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.search_on .select_item .label_checkbox span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: museo_sans_cyrl700;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
}


.search_on .select_item .checkbox:checked+label>.checkbox_square {
    border: none;
}

.filter .options .search_on .select_item .label_checkbox span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: museo_sans_cyrl300;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.search_on .select_item .checkbox+label>.checkbox_square {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #aa2b2b;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
.animate_background, .search_on .select_item .checkbox+label>.checkbox_square {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
.search_on .select_item .label_checkbox span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: museo_sans_cyrl700;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.search_on .select_item .checkbox:checked+label>.checkbox_square:before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #791717, #aa2b2b);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #791717, #aa2b2b);
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.search_on .select_item .checkbox:checked+label>.checkbox_square:after {
    content: "";
    width: 14px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 58;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_on">
                    <div class="select_item">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox check" id="on_PHOTO" name="NOT_PHOTO">
                        <label class="label_checkbox" for="on_PHOTO">
                            <span class="checkbox_square"></span>
                            <span class="checkbox_label">С фото</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант №1.** Центрирование по горизонтали

Нет. Нужно добавить блоку с классом `.select_item` свойство `text-align: center;` вида:

```
.select_item {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Тогда `label` займет центральное положение внутри блока.

`.select_item` - это твой блок в котором находится строчный элемент label 
Задав родительскому блоку свойство `text-align: center;` мы центрировали все дочерние строчные элементы

**Вариант №2.** Центрирование по горизонтали и вертикали (центр блока)

`Div` с классом `select_item` имеет высоту и ширину дочернего `label`. 
Первоначально задаем ему фиксированную высоту и ширину внутри которой мы будем центрировать. Далее укажем ему свойство `display: flex;`

```
.select_item {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
}
```

Теперь центрируем сам `label` указав свойству `margin` значение `auto`. Это позволит автоматически подобрать вертикальные и горизонтальные отступы внутри блока.

```
.label_checkbox {
        margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: имеется ввиду по вертикали...?

Comment: Добавила ваш код, по-моему, ничего не изменилось по горизонтали...